# vba- open IE on VBA and let it open the homepages

Tags: internet-explorer, excel, vba

I set my homepages to several different websites on IE, but when I open IE using my VBA code below, nothing shows up as the homepage. How should I modify the code so that IE opens up with the pre-set homepages?

```
Sub OpenIE()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.GoHome` method.

```
objIE.GoHome
```

More at [InternetExplorer object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).